# How to run python in windows 7

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am new to python. i am try to run my first hello world program but i got an error msg.

please find below the screen shot

[image]

Error Msg look like this:

**>>> print "hello"**

**File "" line1**

**print "hello"
            ^**

**SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `Python 3`, In this version `print` is not a keyword it is a `function`.
Try this :

```
print("hello")
```

See changes in [Python3 from Python 2](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function)